# Нужно создать алгоритм выведения на экран середины введенной с клавиатуры строки на языке Python

Tags: python, строки

Нужно создать такой алгоритм, чтобы при введении слова через клавиатуру подсчитывалось количество знаков и проверялось чётное или не чётное число, а после на основе этого вырезалась середина слова. Если четное число должно выводиться два средних символа, если нечетное один символ.

Это мой код, который я пытался писать:

```py
str_1 = input("Input str_1:")

len(str_1)
if len(str_1) % 2 == 0:
    print(len(str_1) // 2 - 1)
else:
    print(len(str_1) // 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Пусть `length = len(str_1)` — длина строки, тогда `middle = length // 2` — индекс одного из средних символов. Если сама строка имеет нечётное количество символов, то `middle` — искомый индекс, иначе нужно ещё учесть предудщий символ (т.к. полученный нами `middle` ВСЕГДА обозначает индекс второго среднего символа).

Для вывода двух средних символов можно воспользоваться срезом `[middle-1:middle+1]`, который выведет символы с индексами от `middle-1` до `middle+1` не включая (т.е. только `str_1[middle-1]` и `str_1[middle]`), для одного символа — просто `str_1[middle]`.

```py
str_1 = input("Input str_1:")

length = len(str_1)
middle = length // 2
if length % 2 == 0:
    print(str_1[middle-1:middle+1])
else:
    print(str_1[middle])
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но код, который вы написали не совсем правильно работает . Когда я ввожу не четное число. он показывает 2 символа

Comment: @ФедорДавыдов то есть Вы вводите какое-либо число, а не просто строку? Из вашего изначального условия следует, что чётность должна быть для длины строки, и не для числа, вводимого как строку =/

Comment: Да, четное количество символов строки

Comment: @ФедорДавыдов ну вот, но ведь когда Вы вводите нечётное число, то оно имеет чётное количество цифр, верно? В таком случае, действительно, выведутся две цифры, как и требовалось

Comment: Все работает корректно,  если ввести слово мама ,  то выводится ам, т.е два символа как и было указано в задании. А если ввести краб  ,  то выводится а  . И что здесь не правильно работает ?

Comment: @VasilijsLaskovskis, надеюсь, после "краб" стоит пробел, потому что если Вы вводили "краб" без пробела... =/

Comment: Очевидно не дописалась буква  'ы'

Comment: В слове краб должно выводиться не а, а ра. А если слова допустим пир, то должно выводиться и.

Comment: @ФедорДавыдов комментатор выше забыл "ы", так то на "краб" должно вывестись "а", а на "пир" — "и"

Answer (score 0):

`i == j` если `n` нечётное. `i + 1 == j` если `n` чётное. `s[i:j + 1]` вырезает из строки кусочек с началом в `i` и с концом в `j`:

```
s = input()          #    abdc    abcde 
n = len(s)           #     4        5
i = (n - 1) // 2     #     1        2
j = n // 2           #     2        2
print(s[i:j + 1])    #     bd       c
```

> ```
> $ echo abcd | python mid.py
> bc
>
> $ echo abcde | python mid.py
> c
> ```